# Xampp unable to load multiple sites

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, virtualhost

I am working on a project using `xampp` server. I have more than one project. So for this I have set my `httpd-vhosts` like below

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  
  ServerName khpos.com
  ServerAlias www.khpos.com

  DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/pos"


<Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/pos">
   Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
 #my second site
<VirtualHost *:8080>

ServerName demopos.com
ServerAlias www.demopos.com

 DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/demopos"


<Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/demopos">
   Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Whenever I try to hit `localhost:8080/demopos` it's redirecting towards `.../pos`

**hosts file**

```
127.0.0.1:8080      khpos.com
127.0.0.1:8080      demopos.com
```

How to set it

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should change the portnumbers of the second etc. sites. Now all port addresses are on port 8080, if you change those to an other port number you should be fine.

`<VirtualHost *:8080>` to `<VirtualHost *:{port-number}>`

Where port-number is an other port-number

```
127.0.0.1:8080               khpos.com
127.0.0.1:{port-number}      demopos.com
```

Comment: Now it's giving me `This page isn’t working`

Comment: Dit you change it on both the host file and virtualhost file?

Comment: yes i changed on both `httpd-vhosts` , `httpd.conf` and `hosts` files

Comment: But that isn't a `404 not found` so might there be a problem in your code file itself?

Comment: The code is same it's still working for `.../pos`

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 virtual hosts defined and also the names in hosts file. Please first remove the port numbers in the hosts file:

```
ServerName khpos.com
ServerName demopos.com
```

```
127.0.0.1    khpos.com
127.0.0.1    demopos.com
```

if you call khpos.com:8080 or demopo.com:8080 it should reach your correct virtual hosts.

But: if you call localhost:8080 it will match none of your virtual hosts.

In that case Apache always enters the first virtual host matching the port that you have in your conf file ignoring its server name. That is a strange behavior of Apache - in my opinion a bug. It is exactly what you observe.

For that reason I always place a dummy virtual server in front of all others that can catch all non fitting requests with a dummy message in a simple html file.

Just a hint: you have defined

```
DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/pos"
```

so there currently is no khpos.com:8080/pos because pos is part of the root unless you create another folder pos below

Comment: `khpos.com:8080` and `demopos.com:8080` not working either :(

Comment: I just saw that I overlooked the mistake in the hosts file. Answer updated.

Comment: updated the hosts file. Again same issue `This page isn’t working`

Comment: please give the complete error message including what you get in access.log and error.log. Do you have a index.html in the root directory?

Comment: another hint: I assume that the message "This page isn't working" is generated AFTER accessing the virtual host directories e.g. in executing php. So I would recommend to check the access to the virtual host first by just placing index.html with a simple text in the root folder. Check if it is served and displayed in the browser and then proceed with further content.

Comment: I placed an `index.html` file and then try to access the url and it does work